# wrap log statement in single line in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

How to wrapp all log.debug or log.info statement in single line in intellij.

Example:
//it it formated like this in Intellij.

```
log.debug("param1 {}, param 2 {}, param 3 {},  param 4 {}",
param1,
param2,
param3,
param4);
```

But I want like this.

```
log.debug("param1 {}, param 2 {}, param 3 {}, param 4 {}",param1,param2,param3,param4);
```

I tried with "simple statement  singleline" doesnt help.

is there any where I can configure like log.debug statements should be in single line.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Method call arguments set to **Do not wrap**
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Keep when reformatting | **Line breaks** disabled.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this *just for log statements*?